User object in Next-Auth SignIn callback is wrong
I am using Next-Auth for authentication in my app. For a very weird reason, when I login via gmail for an email account (lets call it ttt@gmail.com), the user parameter in the signIn callback is showing a different user. When I try other gmail accounts, the user object is correctly populated, and I have made sure to logout but that email address (ttt@gmail.com) always loads the wrong user account. The email address (ttt@gmail.com) is also not created in the database. What could be going on, I'm stumped.
//auth.ts code:
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@auth/prisma-adapter';
import routes from '@/lib/config/routes';
import Google from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import { sendVerificationRequest } from './sendEmail';
import Resend from 'next-auth/providers/resend';


import prisma from '../init/prisma';

export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  auth,
  signIn,
  signOut
} = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Google({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
    }),
    Resend({
      apiKey: process.env.RESEND_API_KEY,
      from: process.env.RESEND_FROM_EMAIL,
      server: process.env.RESEND_SERVER,
      sendVerificationRequest
    })
  ],
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  session: { strategy: 'database' },
  pages: {
    signIn: routes.redirects.auth.toLogin
  },
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, user }) {
      if (user || session) {
        session.user.id = user.id;
        return session;
      }

      throw 'User Not Found';
    },

    // New signIn callback to add user to default demo organization on first login
    async signIn({user, account, profile, email })  {
      try {
        const demoOrgId = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DEMO_ORG_ID;

         return true; // Continue with sign-in
      }

       catch(error) {
      console.error("Error adding user to demo organization:", error);
      return false; // Cancel sign-in if an error occurs
    }
  }
}
});

